# Remove the down arrow in JComboBox

Tags: java, swing, intellij-idea

I want to create an auto complete program and I am using `JComboBox` for this.

Now I want to remove the down arrow in the `JComboBox`. How to remove the arrow?

Comment: why? dont invent ui widgets, users will get confused!

Comment: because I want to appear like when you search in the Google, you cant see any arrow down there and that is exactly what I want to appear in my JComboBox. Any Idea about this matter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[JComboBox](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html) is compound [JComponent](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/index.html) and contains [JButton](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html) with [Icon](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/icon.html), you can remove that by setIcon(null) or replace with another Icon

for example  (how to do it with simple steps, NOTICE valid just for `Metal Look and Feel`)

```
        JComboBox coloredArrowsCombo = myComboBox;
        BufferedImage coloredArrowsImage = null;
        try {
            coloredArrowsImage = ImageIO.read(AppVariables.class.getResource("resources/passed.png"));
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(someClessName.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        if (!(coloredArrowsImage == null)) {
            Icon coloredArrowsIcon = new ImageIcon(coloredArrowsImage);
            Component[] comp = coloredArrowsCombo.getComponents();
            for (int i = 0; i < comp.length; i++) {
                if (comp[i] instanceof MetalComboBoxButton) {
                    MetalComboBoxButton coloredArrowsButton = (MetalComboBoxButton) comp[i];
                    coloredArrowsButton.setComboIcon(coloredArrowsIcon);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
```

EDIT: for better output you can put here `coloredArrowsButton.setRolloverIcon(someIcon);`