# Hide JComBox Box Arrow

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

Is it possible to hide the arrow displayed in the JComboBox

I tried setting:

```
combo.getComponent(0).setSize(new Dimension(1,1));
```

But it doesnt seem to work

Comment: duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7243135/how-to-remove-the-arrow-down-in-the-jcombobox)

Comment: and duplicate comment: why? dont invent ui widgets, users will get confused!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to create a new combobox UI for that:

```
combo.setUI(new BasicComboBoxUI() {
    protected JButton createArrowButton() {
        return new JButton() {
            public int getWidth() {
                return 0;
            }
        };
    }
});
```

But be careful to inherited from the base UI which matches your current look and feel.

For example if you are using Substance you should derive your new UI from `SubstanceComboBoxUI` instead of `BasicComboBoxUI`. Otherwise you'll might loose features provided by your current L&F.

**EDIT:** If you want this to get some kind of auto-completion feature it's better to stick with a normal `JTextField` and use `AutoCompleteDecorator` from [SwingX](http://swingx.java.net/).

Comment: thanx. Also, I noticed, when I click on the space where the Down Arrow was drawn, the combobox drops down, is it possible avoid this behavior too?

Comment: -1 for brittle hack ... @Akash if you don't want combobox behaviour, then don't use a combo

Comment: @DR. please change that with returns AbstractButton with Icon#null

Comment: @mKorbel: Why would I do that? `BasicComboBoxUI.createArrowButton` must return a `JButton`. (http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/plaf/basic/BasicComboBoxUI.html#createArrowButton%28%29)

Comment: @Akash: In that case it looks like you want have the visuals of a normal text field with a list of proposals. In that case have a look at `AutoCompleteDecorator` from SwingX. (Updated my answer)

Comment: @kleopatra: wanted to have a TextField that functions like Autocomplete (behaviour same as JCombo)

Comment: Thanks for the help guys, shall try AutoCompleteDecorator from Swing X

Answer (score 4):

I've been looking for a solution to this for a while now, and it turns out that all it really takes is remembering that `JComboBox` is a compound component.

```
for (Component component : TheComboBox.getComponents())
{
    if (component instanceof JButton) {
        TheComboBox.remove(component);
    }
}
```

Thanks go to [mKorbel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/714968/mkorbel) for the [reminder](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7243394/1188897).