# Java remove JComboBox arrow button

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

I added a JComboBox from the palette using netbeans IDE and populated it with contents from mysql database. I also added autocomplete functionality using swingx-all-1.6.5-1

**method for populating combobox**

```
    public void doPopulateCombo(){
    Connection con = Functions.ConnectToDB();
    try {
        Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
        String sqlQuery = "select * from products";
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sqlQuery);

        while(rs.next()){
            String product_name = rs.getString("Product_Name");
            cboProducts.addItem(product_name);
        }
        con.close();
        cboProducts.setSelectedIndex(-1);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Error populating combo box\n"+e.toString(),
                "Error",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }
}
```

How do I remove the combobox's arrow button so that it appears like a textbox?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hide JComBox Box Arrow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7485832/hide-jcombox-box-arrow)

Comment: Not really, removes the arrow button but changes autocomplete behaviour. It does not select the autosuggested item in the list. Any suggestions on how you can do that?

Comment: The accepted answer in the above link has an alternate solution using `JTextField` and `AutoCompleteDecorator`.

Answer (score 0):

The best I can come up with is putting it into a JPanel that's slightly smaller than it, but depending on the L&F that's not really the best way to do it. Alternatively you could make a class that extends JComboBox, overrides the paint(Graphics g) method and from there calls the paint method of a textbox with the same dimensions. At least, I think you could do that, if you wanted to. Do note that you'd have to update what's in the textbox each time the user selects an option.

Answer (score 0):

A hacky way to fix this would be to create your own implementation of BasicComboBoxUI and override createArrowButton()

```
public class NoArrowJComboBoxUI extends BasicComboBoxUI {

    @Override
    protected JButton createArrowButton() {
        JButton btn = new JButton();
        btn.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(0,0));
        btn.setVisible(false);
        return btn;
    }

}
```

Then in your existing code:

```
    cboProducts.setSelectedIndex(-1);
    cboProducts.setUI(new NoArrowJComboBoxUI());
```

This implementation should not interfere with autocomplete behavior, however, I haven't tested it myself with autocomplete so I can't say that with certainty.

Comment: It does interfere a little bit in that autosuggested item is not automatically selected on the list, just autocompleted on the combobox